# Update Biopython in Ipython shell

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, biopython

python newbie here, today I updated biopython to v1.70. I use spyder/IPython shell for most of my work. if it makes any sense, the version of biopython seems updated in the python console (spyder), and windows command terminal python installation, but IPython console is still showing older version. Should that be updated separately, and if yes, how. Thanks for answers.

Comment: How did you update the `biopython` package? Are Spyder and IPython using the same Python executable (I assume Anaconda)?

Comment: I used pip to update, in a windows command terminal.                                                       `pip --install --upgrade biopython`                                                                                                              I checked path to python from windows terminal and IPython, its the same. And yes it is Anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda on Windows, using the Command Prompt (what you get when typing `cmd` or clicking on *Command Prompt* in the Start menu) is discouraged<sup>1</sup> since the latest release (May '17).

Instead, use  *Anaconda Prompt* or the graphical *Anaconda Navigator* (both located under the *Anaconda* folder in the Start menu). You should use them for installing packages, as well as for running apps (e.g. Spyder, IPython).

Also, I recommend you use `conda` to install packages. `conda` is the native package manager for Anaconda, and it manages dependencies (packages required to run other packages) better than `pip`.

#### So, what you can try is:

*Start* --> *Anaconda Prompt*, and then

```
conda install biopython
ipython
```

At the time of writing, the official `conda` repository contains `biopython` 1.6.9. If you really need 1.7.0, use `conda install -c conda-forge biopython` (`conda-forge` is an alternative package repository which is maintained by the community).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> See the 2nd bullet on Anaconda 4.4.0 [release notes](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/release-notes#what-s-new-in-anaconda-4-4).