# How can I launch Spyder from Anaconda Tensorflow environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, python-import, python-3.6

I have already downloaded tensorflow library via Anaconda,but I am unable to launch Spyder inside tensorflow environment, and I also cannot import tensorflow in the Anaconda prompt.

The following are the specifications:

python version : 3.6.1.final.0
platform : win-64
conda version : 4.3.21
conda is private : False
conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : not installed
requests version : 2.14.2

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\tf_should_use.py", line 28, in <module>
    from backports import weakref  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
ImportError: cannot import name 'weakref'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you either:

1. Followed the installation process for the Python 3.5 version of TensorFlow (unfortunately, the 3.6 process is not currently documented on TensorFlow website).
2. Followed the right process - but did it through the *Windows Command Prompt*, and not through *Anaconda Prompt* (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489932/update-biopython-in-ipython-shell/45600338#45600338) why this is bad).
3. Somehow messed up your Spyder installation.

... or some combination thereof.

#### Anyway, the following should cover everything:

Open *Start* --> *Anaconda Prompt*, and then:

```
conda create -n tensorflow36 anaconda python=3.6
activate tensorflow36
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
spyder
```

Note the `conda create` command will take a while to finish.

You should now have a shortcut in your Start Menu (under *Anaconda* group) called *"Spyder (tensorflow36)"* which you can use to start the right Spyder environment going forward.

Now, to make sure everything installed correctly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Comment: @Ayca, did my answer help you? If it did, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when followed the instructions to install Tensorflow in the official website, but Spyder was not recognizing Tensorflow. It said that the module was not installed.

The problem is that Tensorflow and Spyder were installed in different Anaconda environments.

I solved it by changing the environment in Anaconda Navigator and installing Spyder inside the environment I had Tensorflow.

By executing this installation of Spyder i managed to succesfully with Tensorflow.

[image: environment_anaconda_spyder]